# Replacing characters in all output of a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Lets say I have a function

```py
def print_func():
    print('this')
    print('that')
    print('the other one')
```

And I will call this function multiple times.
The first time I was looking for the output

```
this
that
the other one
```

I would do

```py
print_func()
```

Simple enough, but what if I wanted to call it another time, and this time I was looking for the output

```
this that the other one
```

And a third time I wanted

```
this
that
the last one
```

What would be the best way to implement this?

**EDIT:**
I almost have it with

```py
def print_func(repfrom, repto):
    print('this\n'.replace(repfrom, repto), end='')
    print('that\n'.replace(repfrom, repto), end='')
    print('the other one\n'.replace(repfrom, repto), end='')
#print them on seperate lines
print_func('', '')
#print them all on the same line
print_func('\n', ' ')
#replace other with last
print_func('other', 'last')
```

But the output its giving me is

```
this
that
the other one
this that the other one this
that
the last one
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def print_func(on_newline):
    print(('\n' if on_newline else ' ').join('this', 'that', 'the other one'))

print_func(True)
print_func(False)
print_func(True)
```

The best implementation I can think of

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the separator as an argument to the function:

```
def print_func(separator):
    print('this', 'that', 'the other one', sep=separator)
```

Your three function calls would then be:

```
print_func('\n')
print_func(' ')
print_func('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the *best* way to implement this type of thing in general, but given your example it's the simplest I can think of:

```
>>> def print_func(output=[
...     "this\nthat\nthe last one",
...     "this that the other one",
...     "this\nthat\nthe other one",
... ]):
...     print(output.pop())
...
>>> print_func()
this
that
the other one
>>> print_func()
this that the other one
>>> print_func()
this
that
the last one
```

For a less contrived example, a generator might be better, or perhaps a method on an object that implements some kind of state machine -- it all depends on what the actual desired behavior is and the easiest way to model it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Code is:

```
def print_func(repfrom='', repto=''):
    print('this\n'.replace(repfrom, repto), end='')
    print('that\n'.replace(repfrom, repto), end='')
    print('the other one\n'.replace(repfrom, repto), end='')
#print them on seperate lines
print_func()
#print them all on the same line
print_func('\n', ' ')
print()
#replace other with last
print_func('other', 'last')
```